# How to set up a mining pool on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, linux

I know a similar question has already been asked, but it was 3 years ago, so I asked the question again so that the methods are relevant

Comment: You can try my [monero mining pool](https://monero.herominers.com/) for solo mining. https://monero.herominers.com/

Comment: RUN IT WITH SUDO 1. git clone https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig.git 2. cd xmrig/ 3. apt-get install git build-essential cmake libuv1-dev libssl-dev libhwloc-dev 4. sudo mkdir xmrig/build && cd xmrid/build 5. cd xmrig/build/ 6. cmake .. 7. make -j$(nproc) 8. nano config.json 9. Then go to xmrig and use wizard to make a config.json file --Enter your XMR wallet address,location,device name 10. Then copy the text into config file under build 11. sudo ./xmrg 12. CTRL + C to stop. 13. THANKS

Comment: The question is how to run a pool, not a miner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [nodejs-pool](https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool) for a javascript pool or [monero-pool](https://github.com/jtgrassie/monero-pool) for a C based pool.